# This question appears to have been migrated from programmers.SE twice

Tags: support

First as:

[Reversing a string](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1586/is-it-better-to-put-more-logic-in-a-for-loop-condition-or-to-use-a-while-loop)

And then again as:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1697/is-it-better-to-put-more-logic-in-a-for-loop-condition-or-to-use-a-while-loop

Comment: I have cast a vote to close as an exact duplicate but I think it would be better to just have it deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question's migration history was cleared on Programmers. It was migrated again to close it on Programmers. I have merged the answers and deleted the duplicate.